# How to generate ranges of random values on x columns and y rows that sum up to specific values on rows and columns in EXCEL 2007

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I am trying to dynamically generate random values from 0 to 5 in 3 separate columns and a changing number of rows. The values must sum up to 5 on  each row and to a specific value on column. The sum of the column is different in each column.

My sheet calculates the needed value on each of the 3 columns and the needed number of rows.

I have average skills with formulas an none with VBA, but interested to learn.

[image: trying to achieve]

Comment: I tried to RANDBETWEEN 1 and 5 until the column sum is the value that i need on first colum and then conditions on the next 2 columns so that the sum stays 5. Even if some times it gave the right value on one column the other 2 where off.

Comment: I event tried to experiment with cross-reference looping enabled but stil no satisfying result.

Comment: Is it a set number of rows?

Comment: The number of rows changes from case to case, it can be 1 it can be 200. So it needs to be dependent on the number of rows calculated for a specific case. Also, the sum that is needed on each column is calculated specifically from case to case.

Comment: One more thing, like i said I have 0 knowledge with VBA and I don't want to waste anyone's time. I tried to figure out how to use the VBA code with my sheet but failed. the code needs to run in sheet 10 range L28 to N142, the number of rows is calculated in cell C23 and the columns sums are in cells P6, Q6 and R6.

Comment: Hold tight, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

The following code uses the number found in column B and calculates a random numbers, looping until it finds the last row in column B. The axis are fully formatted by the macro. The only thing this macro requires to run are values in column B.
The code has been heavily commented for further explanation.

### Steps on how to include the macro in your workbook

- Step 1: Open VBA (hotkey while in Excel: alt-F11)
- Step 2:

  - a) If you have more than one sheet open, navigate to the correct worksheet. The names are listed on the left hand menu.

    [image]
  - b) Because this code defines the sheet (`Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")`), you can copy/paste this code into in either the worksheet it is going to run in (in this example, it would be `Sheet1`), `Thisworkbook`, or you can add it into a module (`Module1` in the picture). Remember to give the `Sub` a better name than "test" :)

### Steps on how to create a button

- Step 1: If your Excel does not have the option for you to create a button from your title bar, follow these steps else skip to Step 2.

  - a) Click the dropdown in your title bar 
    [image]
  - b) Click "More Commands..."
  - c) Click "Choose commands from:" and select "Developer Tab"
  - d) Click "Design Mode" then click Add>>. Design Mode will let you click a button without activating the macro. This option will now display on your title bar. [image]
  - e) Click "Insert Controls" then click Add>>. Insert Controls will be the option to create a button. This option will now display on your title bar.[image]
- Step 2:

  - a) Click on the Insert Controls icon on your title bar.
  - b) Click "Button (Form Control)" (upper left option).

    [image]
  - c) Your mouse cursor will now be a cross hair when you hover over cells within your workbook. Click and drag to create a button.
  - d) You will be automatically prompted to select a macro to assign to the button. Choose the macro you just copy/pasted.

Step 3: Click your button / enjoy your macro.

---

### Code (tested)

```
Sub test()
    ' dim your variables. this tells vba what type of variable it is working with
    Dim lRow As Long
    ' defining wb is easier than typing out ThisWorkbook everytime
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    ' defining ws is easier than typing out Worksheets("Sheet1") everytime
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ' find the last row in column b (2) in the above defined ws
    lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    ' loop through rows 3 to last row
    For i = 3 To lRow
        ' generate a random number between 0 and the row contents of column B (5)
        ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = Int(Rnd() * (ws.Cells(i, 2).Value + 1))
        ' generate a random number between 0 and the difference between column B and colum C
        ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = Int(Rnd() * (ws.Cells(i, 2).Value - ws.Cells(i, 3).Value))
        ' subtract the difference between column B and the sum of column C and column D
        ws.Cells(i, 5).Value = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value - (ws.Cells(i, 3).Value + ws.Cells(i, 4).Value)
    Next i

    ' sum column C (column 3) and place the value in C2
    ws.Cells(2, 3).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(3, 3), Cells(lRow, 3)))
    ' sum column D (column 4) and place the value in D2
    ws.Cells(2, 4).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(3, 4), Cells(lRow, 4)))
    ' sum column E (column 5) and place the value in E2
    ws.Cells(2, 5).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(3, 5), Cells(lRow, 5)))

    ' format from A3 to the last row in column A - cell alignment / merge cells / value
    With ws.Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(lRow, 1))
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
        .Value = "row sum"
    End With

    ' format from C1 to E1 - cell alignment / merge cells / value
    With ws.Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(1, 5))
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
        .Value = "column sum"
    End With

    ' format from B3 to the last row in column B - color formatting
    With ws.Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(lRow, 2)).Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 5296274
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

    ' format from C2 to E2 - color formatting
    With ws.Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(2, 5)).Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 5296274
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried the code and it doesn't seem to count for the given column sum and it just updates it to the sum of the cells. Also, i can't get it to expand to more rows.

Comment: NP. I've updated my answer to include the axis titles and color formatting. It will also automatically detect the last row for you.

Comment: Thank you again for your help. I was able to follow everything but there is one issue. The code works great in generating the needed number of rows with data but that is only the first condition. The numbers generated randomly on each of the 3 columns must add up (on each column) to a specific number that is calculated elsewhere on the sheet.

Comment: For example, i need 30 rows A2 to A31 (the value 30 is calculated in A1) with the sum of each row to be 5 and 3 columns (B,C,D) with random data from 0 to 5. The sum of each column is an input value (like the number of rows in the first code) and for this example the values must be 32 (for column B located in B1), 25 (for column C located in C1) and 93 (for column D located in D1). So the code must generate a matrix in the range B2 to D31 and in this matrix the sum of each row is 5 and the sum of column B must be the one in B1, the sum of C the one in C1 and the sum of D must be the one in D1.

Comment: Also the formatting of the cells is not necessary I made it like that just to be a little more clear of what i'm asking. This values go into a very different table and are basis for further calculations.

Comment: @Mech This is a great code. What if the B column values are not all the same? (in this example all of them was 5) Is this achievable?

Comment: @Mech I asked this with a bounty here if you could help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74556221/generate-random-numbers-based-on-row-and-colum-totals