# Generate random numbers based on row and colum totals

Tags: excel, vba

I would like populate the blue area with random numbers.

sum of C3 to R3 should be equal to B3 value: 124
also;
sum of C3 to C26 should be equal to C2 value: 705

I tried to achieve it with the following code:
(this code was originally posted here: [Code by @Mech](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60637394/how-to-generate-ranges-of-random-values-on-x-columns-and-y-rows-that-sum-up-to-s)

```
Sub RandomNumbersArray()
    ' dim your variables. this tells vba what type of variable it is working with
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("SPLIT BY DAYS")
    ' find the last row in column b (2) in the above defined ws
    lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    ' loop through rows 3 to last row
    For i = 3 To lRow
        ' generate a random number between 0 and the row contents of column B (5)
        ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = Int(Rnd() * (ws.Cells(i, 2).Value + 1))
        
        ' generate a random number between 0 and the difference between column B and colum C
        ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = Int(Rnd() * (ws.Cells(i, 2).Value - ws.Cells(i, 3).Value))
        
        ' subtract the difference between column B and the sum of column C and column D
        ws.Cells(i, 5).Value = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value - (ws.Cells(i, 3).Value + ws.Cells(i, 4).Value)
        
        ' subtract the difference between column B and the sum of column C and column D and column E
        ws.Cells(i, 6).Value = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value - (ws.Cells(i, 3).Value + ws.Cells(i, 4).Value + ws.Cells(i, 5).Value)
        
        ' subtract the difference between column B and the sum of column C and column D and column E and column F
        ws.Cells(i, 7).Value = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value - (ws.Cells(i, 3).Value + ws.Cells(i, 4).Value + ws.Cells(i, 5).Value + ws.Cells(i, 6).Value)
    Next i

    ' sum column C (column 3) and place the value in C2
    ws.Cells(2, 3).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(3, 3), Cells(lRow, 3)))
    ' sum column D (column 4) and place the value in D2
    ws.Cells(2, 4).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(3, 4), Cells(lRow, 4)))
    ' sum column E (column 5) and place the value in E2
    ws.Cells(2, 5).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(3, 5), Cells(lRow, 5)))
    ' sum column F (column 6) and place the value in F2
    ws.Cells(2, 6).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(3, 6), Cells(lRow, 6)))
    ' sum column G (column 7) and place the value in F2
    ws.Cells(2, 7).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(3, 7), Cells(lRow, 7)))
End Sub
```

[image]

EDIT: Just to clarify, no negative numbers.

Comment: Why? I ask because I'm not sure about your question. Look in the documentation for `Random` to learn about setting limits.

Comment: Why do you think Tom downvoted your question? It might have been any other user. Your question was downvoted because you didn't show any attempts you made, you just wrote a list of requirements.

Comment: @FunThomas Fair point I added my code attempt.

Comment: The sum needs to be what's in Column 2 per row but also the column's 2'nd row value but you're setting the value in the end to the sum instead of making the numbers random fitting to the determinated sum.

Comment: So it's more like you want to get the random values adding up to the B column values and then get the sum of the columns as well (calculated after)?

Comment: @Notus_Panda exactly

Comment: @Notus_Panda At the end, sums for row and the column should match the pre determined values, while the numbers can be randomly distributed. By the way, total value for row and column are matching of course. 3492 in this example. I think, the method should consider the total value (3492) while calculating.

Comment: You can't tell me "exactly" and then say the complete opposite :p
In your attempt the sum of the columns is calculated after calculating all the rows 3-26. In what you're asking in your last comment, it's pre-calculated and adds another difficulty to how a cell value is calculated. Unless you meant the total value of rows and columns are matching which is normal since you're counting all numbers together then.

Comment: @Notus_Panda By exactly I meant, when you sum C2:R2 is equal to sum of B3:B26 which is 3492 in this example :) Blue area will be random numbers while two criteria at the end matching. Also, the numbers in C2:R2 and B3:B26 ranges, should not be modified, after calculation.

Comment: In the picture example you've given, the 24 cells in column R should total 16 - this isn't possible unless some of those cells have values that are less than 1.

Comment: @SpencerBarnes you are correct. Numbers were random. Zeros should be fine. Thanks.

Comment: @Vetuka I've just edited my answer to prevent negative values, zeroes are obviously still present. I'll delete my first (incorrect) answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution.
Answers so far have mostly been about finding values which are random, then fixing them to fit the totals.

I tried finding a calculated (non random) solution that fits the totals, then made a separate sub to randomize it. This way you can prevent the randomization from introducing negative values.

There are two procedures, This sub will call them both on the same Range.

```
Sub Call_Random_Array
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("SPLIT BY DAYS")
Dim RangeToFill as Range: Set RangeToFill = ws.Range("C3:R26") 'Edit this line to select whatever range you need to fill randomly

'Proportionately fill the array to fit totals:
Call ProportionateFillArray(RangeToFill)

'Randomize it x times
For x = 1 to 10 'increase this number for more randomisation
    Call RandomizeValues(RangeToFill)
Next

End Sub
```

### Proportionately fill the array to fit totals:

```
Sub ProportionateFillArray(rngAddress As Range)
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = rngAddress.Worksheet

'Horizontal and Vertical target values as ranges:
Dim hTarg As Range, vTarg As Range
Set hTarg = rngAddress.Rows(1).Offset(-1, 0)
Set vTarg = rngAddress.Columns(1).Offset(0, -1)

'Check the totals match
If Not WorksheetFunction.Sum(hTarg) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(vTarg) Then
    'totals don't match
    MsgBox "Change the targets so both the horizontal and vertical targets add up to the same number."
    Exit Sub
End If

With rngAddress
    
    'Now fill rows and columns with integers
    Dim Row As Long, Col As Long
    For Row = 1 To .Rows.Count
        For Col = 1 To .Columns.Count
            .Cells(Row, Col) = Int( _
                hTarg.Cells(Col) * vTarg.Cells(Row) / WorksheetFunction.Sum(hTarg) _
                )
        Next
    Next
    
    'Correct rounding errors
    For Row = 1 To .Rows.Count
        For Col = 1 To .Columns.Count
            If Row = .Rows.Count Then
                'Last row, so this column must be corrected come what may
                .Cells(Row, Col) = .Cells(Row, Col) - WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Columns(Col)) + hTarg.Cells(Col)
            ElseIf Col = .Columns.Count Then
                'Last column, so must be corrected come what may
                .Cells(Row, Col) = .Cells(Row, Col) - WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Rows(Row)) + vTarg.Cells(Row)
            ElseIf _
                (WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Rows(Row)) - vTarg.Cells(Row)) * _
                (WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Columns(Col)) - hTarg.Cells(Col)) > 0 Then
                'both row and column are incorrect in the same direction
                .Cells(Row, Col) = .Cells(Row, Col) - WorksheetFunction.Max( _
                    WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Rows(Row)) - vTarg.Cells(Row), _
                    WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Columns(Col)) - hTarg.Cells(Col))
            End If
        Next
    Next

End With
End Sub
```

### Randomize an array without changing row or column totals:

```
Sub RandomizeValues(rngAddress As Range)
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = rngAddress.Worksheet
Dim rngIncrease(1 To 2) As Range, rngDecrease(1 To 2) As Range, lDiff As Long

With rngAddress
    'Select two cells to increase at random
    For a = 1 To 2
        Set rngIncrease(a) = .Cells(RndIntegerBetween(1, .Rows.Count), RndIntegerBetween(1, .Columns.Count))
        rngIncrease(a).Select
    Next
    
    'Corresponding cells to decrease to make totals the same:
    Set rngDecrease(1) = ws.Cells(rngIncrease(1).Row, rngIncrease(2).Column)
    Set rngDecrease(2) = ws.Cells(rngIncrease(2).Row, rngIncrease(1).Column)
    
    'Set the value to increase/decrease by - can't be more than the smallest rngDecrease Value, to prevent negative values
    If Not WorksheetFunction.Min(rngDecrease) > 1 Then
        'Don't decrease a value below 1
        Exit Sub
    Else
        lDiff = RndIntegerBetween(1, WorksheetFunction.Min(rngDecrease)-1)
    End If
    
    'Now apply the edits
    For a = 1 To 2
        rngIncrease(a) = rngIncrease(a) + lDiff
        rngDecrease(a) = rngDecrease(a) - lDiff
    Next
End With
End Sub

'The below is the Random Integer function, I also used it in my other answer
Function RndIntegerBetween(Min As Long, Max As Long) As Long
RndIntegerBetween = Int((Max - Min + 1) * Rnd + Min)
End Function
```

Comment: And if you want to prevent any zeroes occuring, change the line in the RandomizeValues sub from `lDiff = RndIntegerBetween(1, WorksheetFunction.Min(rngDecrease))` to `lDiff = RndIntegerBetween(1, WorksheetFunction.Min(rngDecrease)-1)`

Answer (score 2):

Here is something to try:

Set all cells to 0. Create a list of all cells (some kind of reference to each cell).

Now, randomly choose a cell from your list, and add 1 to that cell. The very first time, all cells will be 0, except for one, which will now be 1.

For this cell that you just incremented, add up the row and column and see if the sums have been reached. If either the row *or* the column sum has been reached, *remove* this cell reference from the list.

Repeat (randomly choose a cell from those remaining on the list) until the list is empty.

At each iteration you are randomly choosing one of the remaining cells in the reference list (not choosing from all the cells) and this list is getting smaller and smaller as column or row sums are reached.

It should be the case that random cells will increment, and if the columns and sums can in fact be calculated by values without logical inconsistencies, you should fairly quickly reach that point when the reference list falls empty.

Comment: While this is a very interesting way of looking at it, you should remove **all** cell references in said row or column from the list as "one cell defines them all, one to rule them all" (or just: if a max has been achieved, you can't add anymore to it for that row and/or column)

Comment: Since op doesn't specify the desired distribution of the random numbers, this is a viable approach, but of course, it won't lead to a uniform distribution.

Comment: Where did you expect to see uniformity in random numbers? 0 is to be expected in it, no?

Answer (score 0):

This code is for what you were trying to do, not exactly how you explained it though (see comments). If this is what you were looking for, then your explanation was a bit off, otherwise let me know what you did mean.

```
Sub RandomNumbersArray()
    Dim lRow As Long, lColumn As Long, remainingValue As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("SPLIT BY DAYS")
    
    lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    lColumn = ws.Cells(2, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For i = 3 To lRow 'loop through the rows
        remainingValue = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value2
        For j = 3 To lColumn 'loop through all the columns per row
            ' generate a random number between 0 and the row contents of column B - previous column
            If j = lColumn Then 'last cell can't be random unless you want to extend the columns until the sum in B-column is met
                ws.Cells(i, j).Value2 = remainingValue
            Else
                ws.Cells(i, j).Value2 = Int((remainingValue + 1) * Rnd)
            End If
            remainingValue = remainingValue - ws.Cells(i, j).Value2
        Next j
    Next i
    For j = 3 To lColumn 'loop through the columns to set the sum
        ws.Cells(2, j).Value2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(3, j), Cells(lRow, j)))
    Next j
    
End Sub
```

I'm yet to get past the O-column with any value above 0 however

Comment: Thank you for the attempt. Your code changes the values between C2:R2. As you stated while not adding anything after O column.

Comment: If iirc, Vetuka wanted to have both Rows and Columns pre-defined and get random numbers that would fit both criterias but I don't know how to make that happen. @Cyril so less random and more sudoku style (I guess?)

Comment: @Notus_Panda removed my comment; was looking to comment to main, but do need to make changes